# How to join three degrees in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have following tables:

`users(id, name)`
`posts (id, text, userId)`
`comments (id, text, userId, postId)`

I want to return a post, its owner name, its comments, and the owner of each comment. I can't get data for the owner of the comment. I wrote this:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.text, users.id, users.name, comments.text AS commentText, commenters.id, commenters.name
FROM posts
    JOIN users
        ON posts.userId = users.id
    LEFT JOIN comments
        ON posts.id = comments.postId 
            LEFT JOIN users AS commenters
                ON comments.userId = users.id
        WHERE posts.id = @postId
```

The problem with this query is that the commenters.id, and commenters.name columns are coming back blank. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Any chance comments.userId is populated from some other source? If it's a real foreign key, why do you use left outer join?

Comment: @Olaf, it's populated only from one source. I supposed it should be join, but that still does not work! :/

Comment: BTW: "It's" is a contraction for "It is".  Stop using it where you mean "its".

Comment: @olaf, I think it's because if I don't use left join, I will only get posts with comments.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin, for someone who speaks English really well, this is one of my terrible habits. I often make this mistake when I write in a hurry. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, break the query down.

OK, firstly a small correction

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.text, users.id, users.name, comments.text AS commentText, commenters.id, commenters.name
FROM posts
    JOIN users
        ON posts.userId = users.id
    LEFT JOIN comments
        ON posts.id = comments.postId 
            LEFT JOIN users AS commenters
                ON comments.userId = commenters.id
```

(you had users.id, not commenters.id)

secondly, if that doesnt fix it, break the query parts down, to check that the select * from comments, and join users, to check the link to users works. Do the same for posts.. if that works.. let me know and we can look further as to where its going wrong

Comment: Thanks, it was that, and I use using the wrong alias name in the join clause ("users" instead of "commenters").

Comment: Also for performance consider breaking this up and storing part of it as a view in your database.

Comment: @Mohamad depends on the amount of data I guess. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Devraj, I'm actually curious.. suppose it was trying to return around 50 rows... from a db with over 100,000... would a view perform better? I'm a novice in this area!